# emberjs bind data attributes

Tags: ember.js

I am wondering if there is a way to bind data attributes in a template when calling a view.

For example (this doesn't work):

```
 {{ view App.SomeView data-dateBinding="currentDate" }}
```

I have ended up doing it this way:

```
<a {{bindAttr data-date="currentDate"}}></a>
```

There must be a way to do it when calling the view?

Comment: could you precise what do you want to do with this metadata ?

Comment: I am using a date-picker lib "https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker" that will be applied to a non-form element; a button in my case.  I wanted to make a view App.DatePickerButtonView that creates the button and applies the datepicker. The lib is setup to get the date from a data attribute in the dom. I am sure I could change the lib but there are many plugins that use data atributes and I was thinking there must be a way to bind them when calling a view from a template?

Comment: In this case I would just use {{ view App.SomeView dateBinding="currentDate" }}, and call datepicker() from `didInsertElement`

Comment: yes I agree I am using didIsertElement to apply the date picker but the date picker needs the data-date attribute on the element. This question is about if it is possible to bind to data attributes like classNames and attributeBindings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to define in App.SomeView which attributes you want put in the HTML.

```
App.SomeView = Ember.View.extend({
  attributeBindings: ["data-date"]
  .... rest of view
})
```

Now `data-dateBinding` should work:

```
{{view App.SomeView data-dateBinding="currentDate" }}
```

Comment: Although, in your specific case, I'd personally go with @sly7_7's answer and initialize the datepicker from `didInsertElement`

Comment: Arg, I've not tried this. This works indeed :), the funny thing is if you want to define the binding in the view code, you can't because dashed properties cause a syntax error...

Comment: hmm I have tried that but it dosen't add the data-date attribute to the dom element. Here is a example http://jsfiddle.net/d6Yw8/1/.

Comment: based on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/d6Yw8/6/, you can see the data-date attribute. But I'm not sure I'm right since it never changes. How is it expected to work ? If i click on a date, usually the date picker closes, and the data-date attribute is updated ?

Comment: There's two issues here. Firstly, you are using a broken version of ember, ember-pre was released with a bug. You need to use ember-latest

Comment: Secondly, Aaron you are using data-dateBinding and then passing the value rather than a binding, either pass `data-date="2012-02-02"` or `data-dateBinding="object.date"` Here's a fiddle with both examples http://jsfiddle.net/xqhRc/

Answer (score 13):

More on the excellent answer from @kurt-ruppel.

An example using `:` to describe the property for attribute binding, entirely done from the view.

```
App.SomeView = Ember.View.extend({
  attributeBindings: ["date:data-date"],
  date: function() { return '1642-12-06' }
  .... rest of view
})
```

The cleaner template.

```
{{view App.SomeView}}
```

Answer (score 2):

FWIW - and this is in response to @sly7_7's comments from the top answer -, it is possible to specify a data-* attribute binding in the view itself, as opposed to setting it in the template.

Similar to `classNameBindings`, you can prepend a preferred value to the attribute, joining the values with a ':'. Best place to see this in action is probably in [the related ember.js tests](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/6a8137902da56b8b1060fcd0bdb748d5e7ae0092/packages/ember-views/tests/views/view/attribute_bindings_test.js). Gives credence to the value of good testing, seeing as how sometimes it serves as the best documentation.