# EmberJS attributeBinding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js

I saw last post [emberjs bind data attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805942/emberjs-bind-data-attributes) and searched on google found link on emberjs
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html
http://emberjs.com/guides/components/customizing-a-components-element/
But I am not able to understand how to create my own attributebinding.

Taking an example case (It is only my assumption and may be i will far away from real scenario). Please correct me.

HTML file contains :
    {{view App.DatePickerView data-dateBinding="rr"}}

app.js file contains :

```
attributeBindings: ["data-date"],
rr: function() {
  alert("Hello");
},
```

I am completely mess up to know how attributebinding works?

Thanks to all of you in advance.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when you set `data-date` to `rr`? Attribute bindings is usually used to pass values into the view. Within the view, the value for `this.get('data-date')` will just be a string `"rr"`. Check out the console tab here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fufuvodupine/1/edit.

Comment: I think you're confusing binding data attributes with binding standard html attributes. For instance, I often want to add a "disabled" class to a link when the user can't click it. For this case you just have `<a {{bind-attr class="isDisabled:disabled"}}>` in the template and define the boolean function `isDisabled()` in the component (or, previously, controller). Anyway, if you give a bit more of an explanation on what you want to do we can probably give you better advice about how to get it done in Ember.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try reopening your view class?

From the [Ember documentation](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/binding-element-attributes/):

```
Ember.LinkView.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['data-toggle']
});
```

I would also recommend steering away from adding data attributes to HTML elements, and instead use properties on Ember Data models if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is a real example to track `top` and `height` attributes and setup an inline style to the wrapping div

```
attributeBindings: ['customStyle:style'],
customStyle: computed('top', 'height', {
  get() {
      let top = this.get('top');
      let height = this.get('height');
      return `top:${top}px; height:${height}px;`;
  }
})
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Template:

```
{{view App.DatePickerView}}
```

app.js:

```
App.DatePickerView = Ember.View.extend({
    attributeBindings: ["newDate:data-date"]
    newDate: function() {
        return (new Date()).toString();
    }.property()
    // ...
});
```

For more information, see: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_html-attributes